# Function to generate random multidimensional array

Tags: c#

I am creating a function to generate random values for a multidimensional array and I get the error "method must have a return type" and "; expected".
Here is my code:

```
public static Double[,] X Generate_random()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    X = new Double[3, 3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            X[i, j] = rnd.Next(0, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is there an `X` in the function declaration?  And where are you returning anything from the function?

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to write your code like this

```
 public static Double[,] Gerar_Aleatorio() { 
    Random rnd = new Random();              
    Double [,] x;
    x = new Double[3, 3]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
              x[i, j] = rnd.Next(0, 10); 
           } 
     } 
    return x;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare your return type for your method (in this case, `Double[,]`), you need to ensure that all paths through the method will end up returning an instance of that type. This is done using the return statement, which you would just place at the end of the method:

```
return X;
```

However, you never explicitly declare what type `X` is. When defining a variable, you must do: `[Type] [VariableName]` and additionally you can do the assignment on the same line (just as you did for `Random`). So your `X` definition should look like:

```
Double[,] X = new Double[3, 3];
```

Additionally, you have a typo (I assume) in the signature, where you have an `X` in the signature next to the type declaration. That should be removed, so your signature looks like:

```
public static Double[,] Generate_random()
```

Putting that all together, you have:

```
public static Double[,] Generate_random()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    Double[,] X = new Double[3, 3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            X[i, j] = rnd.Next(0, 10);
        }
    }

    return X;
}
```